# Scroll to top of document with jQuery not working correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a smartphone app (iOS) with jQuery. I have 2 divs, one displays a list of events, the other just one event. This is how they look:

```
<div id="output">

            </div>
<div id="single" style="background-color: red;">

</div>
```

First single is hidden on document.ready.

When scrolling down the page and clicking an event it shows #single and hides #output. Now, problem is, it is keeping the current page 'location' for the x + y values rather than going to the top as it would with a new page, so the page appears blank, but the content is out of page view (and cannot scroll). This is how I attempted to bring the document to the top:

```
function showSingle(itemId){

                $('#output').hide();
                $('#single').show();
    $("#single").scrollTop(0);
/* ajax */
}
```

This however does not bring it to the top, have I made an error? Thanks

EDIT:

this is before I click: imgur.com/Mitlp and this is after click: imgur.com/873pO

It should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5uPX.jpg

Second Edit: AJAX inside of the function

```
$.ajax({
                        url: 'http://dev.24323423.co.uk/getSingle.php',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        data: { dbId: itemId },
                        jsonp: 'jsoncallbackSingle',
                        timeout: 8000,
                        success: function(data, status){
                            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                                var linkedPageSingle = '<p><a href="#" onClick="homePage(1)">Back</a></p><h2>'+item.eventName+'</h2>'
                                    + '<p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                                    + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

                                $('#single').append(linkedPageSingle);
                            });
                        },

                        error: function(){
                            $('#single').text('There was an error loading the data.');
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.scrollTo(0,0)` if you are scrolling at the top of the document.

Comment: Hello, yes I have just tried this now without any luck. I dont think I said it on the OP i will make an edit, but it is on an iphone app, not a web app but uses javascript and html rather than objective-c if this makes it any different?

Comment: If you're using HTML and CSS then the app will be using a Webview, right? If so, it's just a chrome-less browser window. Try $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

Comment: Hi @MassivePenguin thanks for the comment, it is still unfortunately not working. This is before I click: imgur.com/Mitlp and this is after click: imgur.com/873pO

Comment: Best guess is that your menu bar ("Kendall MintFest") is covering the top of your document. Maybe add padding to the top of the page?

Comment: @MassivePenguin not a bad idea thanks, tried it however it doesn't change anything, is it possible to have the div position its self no matter where it is to be 0 top 0 bottom? I tried this using position: absolute; top:0;bottom:0 but that didnt work

Comment: I've had another thought (see below), but you could try adding 'position: relative' to the body tag's CSS. One more question though: does the #single div have content when you show it, or are you adding it with the ajax call?

Comment: I am adding the content with AJAX, see OP edit for the ajax inside of the function. I added pos rel and it hasn't changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17695/discussion-between-massivepenguin-and-zomboble)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the scrolling is executing before the first div is truly hidden and the second div is truly visible. Try this:

```
function showSingle(itemId){
    $('#output').hide();
    $('#single').show(0, function(){
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
        /* ajax */
    });
}
```

Comment: Good idea! However still no change :/

Comment: Fast update, sometimes after waiting 5-10 seconds on the ones which are totally gone (further down the page) they 'appear' to slide down pretty quick but choppily from the top of the screen

Comment: Hmm. Try adding a wrapper div around both #output' and '#single' and scrolling to the top of that, maybe? Also, how are you calling 'showSingle()'? Is it on a click() function on a link? If so, make sure you're overriding any default actions (e.g. jump to the top of the page) with preventDefault().

Comment: Yeah, the link is generated here: var linkedPage = '<h2><a href="#" onClick="showSingle('+item.id+')">'+item.eventName+'</a></h2>'
                            + '<p>Date: '+item.date+'</p><p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>'; I added prevent default to the showSingle method and clicking the anchor now does nothing. I also tried the wrapper method without luck.

Comment: Maybe we should move this to chat. I've sent you an invite.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` or `$(document).scrollTop(0);` to scroll the document to the top, instead of `$("#single").scrollTop(0);`.

[`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) sets the top scroll offset value for the selected element, not relative to the document.

If you just want the page to scroll such that `#single` is visible (not way to the top), use `$("#single")[0].scrollIntoView();`.

**Note:** You might want to move the scrolling part to *after* the `show()` and `hide()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have tried this with no luck, I could be wrong but I am thinking because it is in a smartphone as an app, it could be thinking the top of the screen is the top of the document if this makes sense?

Comment: Hey, I have given that a shot and it still isnt working :/ I cant understand why not, see these pics, this is before I click: http://imgur.com/Mitlp and this is after click: http://imgur.com/873pO

Comment: @zomboble Seems like your window is scrolled to top, isn't it?

Comment: Im not sure, it should look like this (colours are for debugging): http://imgur.com/nPGU8

Answer (score 1):

First, thank you those who have helped. However rather than trying to solve the problem that I had I found a way around it. This is what I used:

```
 var linkedPage = '<h2><a href="#" onClick="takeToSingle('+item.id+')">'+item.eventName+'</a></h2>'
                            + '<p>Date: '+item.date+'</p><p>Description: '+item.description+'</p><p>Type: '
                            + item.type+'</p><p id="pageid">'+item.id+'</p>';

                        output.append(linkedPage);

 function takeToSingle(itemId){
                localStorage.setItem("pageID",itemId);
                document.location.href = 'page1.html';
            }
```

This sets a localstorage item and is sent over to page1.html where I retrieve it:

```
 pageId = localStorage.getItem("pageID");
```